# Should Monero use ElGamal commitments instead of Pedersen commitments?

Tags: ringct, cryptography

Following on from the [Q/A](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/11214/7493)
regarding "perfectly hiding and computationally binding" commitments, it is
mentioned ElGamal commitments can be used to flip the commitment properties to
become "perfectly binding and computationally hiding". How does this work and
why doesn't Monero prefer this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's first recap the concept of input and output spaces. In our Pedersen
commitments, we are perfectly hidden because the input space is larger than the
output space - we have a many-to-one relationship. For our binding, the spaces
are the same size, the relationship is one-to-one, so can only be
computationally bound. The inverse of these relationships flips the properties of the scheme. The way ElGamal commitments flip these properties is by
publishing an extra point in the commitment (so the commitment now consists of 2
points). As an example:

```
C1 = xG + aH
C2 = xH
C = (C1, C2)
```

Here, our input space is the tuple `x,a` (two 253 bit scalars) and our output space is the same size, a tuple of two points `C1,C2` (two 253 bit points). This is guaranteed distinct because of the mapping of `x` to `xH` and the fact there can only be *one* input tuple that maps to a single output tuple. It is only computationally hidden because `x` can theoretically be extracted from `C2` and then `xG` can be subtracted from `C1` leaving `aH`, from which `a` can be theoretically extracted. Thus `a` is computationally hidden.

Importantly, it is perfectly bound because an
adversary cannot *open* a commitment to a *different* amount `a` to that which
was originally committed. Or in layman terms, change `a`, `x` will have to
change, verification of the original commitment fails. Or to put another way,
changing `a` or `x`, one cannot construct a matching commitment to that of the
original commitment. It's perfectly bound and computationally hidden.

So there is nothing stopping us switch to using perfectly bound and computationally hidden commitments. However, these come with a serious drawback,
*size*. In a Monero transaction, there are a *lot* of commitments (they are used
in both the ring signatures and range-proofs), and ElGamal commitments require
an extra 32 bytes *each* (the extra point). So given that both properties are
important to not be broken (the hiding of amounts and the binding of the
commitments), and that the computationally strength is considered sufficiently
strong for the foreseeable future (we are some way off being able to solve the
discrete logarithm problem), and that even when the DLP can be effectively
solved, there would be far more pressing problems to face. Therefore deciding on
whether to use computationally/perfectly hidden/bound commitments right now,
boils down to other factors, and in our case this is predominantly the size factor.

Therefore, it's fine for now to use either scheme, though preferable to use the smaller
of the two. By the time the DLP is solvable, and we have implemented a
replacement, all past Pedersen committed amounts will still *remain hidden*, but
there will have to be a new binding & hiding scheme to protect against hidden
inflation.  Which brings us to another subtle reason why the Pedersen
commitments (perfectly hiding and computationally binding) are preferable.
Assuming a replacement *is* found before the DLP is easily solvable, a migration
to a new hiding and binding scheme could be done such that the older, weakened,
bound commitments could be phased out (e.g. marked as untrusted from a certain
point in time) and only the newer scheme trusted for subsequent transactions.
Flipping the scenario, if we used computationally hidden and perfectly bound
commitments now, and the DLP assumption becomes broken, all past amounts would
become known with no migration plan possible that could be used to avert this.
And of course in the worst case scenario, of *not* having a replacement to the
broken DLP assumption (regardless of perfectly/computationally hidden/bound
commitments), there are far more problems than just Monero commitments!
Everyone's coins for any cryptocurrency could be stolen for one thing (e.g. it
would be possible to obtain the private wallet key for a given public wallet
key). SSH/PGP/SSL, all breakable. Thus, one can tend to assume we will have
alternative cryptographic schemes before the DLP is easily solvable - it's more
than just our silly [tic] cryptocurrencies that would be affected.

Hopefully these two posts have helped educate that the phrase "perfectly hiding
and computationally binding" is not some weakness in Monero, but rather refers
to specific properties of commitment schemes. No scheme can be both perfectly
binding and hiding and the computational strength is as strong as we rely on for
all other modern day cryptography applications.

Answer (score 1):

even if the topic is two years old and @jtgrassie's answer is very complete, I think it's worth adding a subtle point in "Pedersen VS ElGamal commitments in Monero".

No doubt Monero uses Pedersen which we can say it's theoretically/perfectly hiding and computationally/imperfectly binding.
However in the broader context of RingCT (where Pedersen Commitments are used), given  a destination-amount commitment defined as:

```
    C = yG + bH
```

(where y is the blinding factor and b the amount)
the protocol mandates that:

(1)     y = H("commitment_mask" | H(rV,t)) = H("commitment_mask" | H(vR,t))

(where t is the output number, (r,R) is the transaction keys couple and (v,V) is the view keys couple)

and the trasaction contains the field:

(2)     amount = b XOR H("amount" | H(rV,t)) = b XOR H("amount" | H(vR,t))

Both (1) and (2) could be calculated if DLP was broken, the only weak-supplemental-protection being that V isn't on-chain (nevertheless it's public, being part of payee address); R instead is written in extra field of transaction.
In that case, it easy to see that it enough to invert (2) (no need to use (1)) to get:

```
    b = amount XOR H("amount" | H(rV,t)) = amount XOR H("amount" | H(vR,t))
```

so we could say, IMHO, that RingCT as a whole is computationally hiding even if Pedersen is theoretically hiding.

And, funny enough, imposing (1) for the blinding factor y means constraining it to:

```
    H("commitment_mask" | H(rV,t)) = H("commitment_mask" | H(vR,t))
```

...and adding a specific commit to constrain the blinding factor is the way by which Pedersen commitments are transformed in ElGamal ones

My2cents ;)