# Potentional Monero future vulnerabilities

Tags: monerod, privacy, security

What happens if Monero has vulnerabilities in the future? Would it be possible that it could expose old transactions information such as addresses and amounts? How likely would this be? I am running my own node through tor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens if Monero has vulnerabilities in the future?

That would very much depend on the vulnerability discovered.

> Would it be possible that it could expose old transactions information such as addresses and amounts?

Addresses *are not* stored on the blockchain, so it wouldn't be possible determine any address from just a past transaction, regardless of the vulnerability. Amounts *are* stored on the blockchain, encrypted, but as these are [perfectly hiding](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/11213/what-is-the-impact-of-having-perfectly-hidden-but-only-computationally-bound-com), one still cannot determine the amount transacted.

Now, of course, some will point to quantum computers one day being able to break ECC and the DLP, but the world has far greater things to worry about if/when that ever comes to fruition.